# Как подставить прошлое сообщение бота к новой команде ? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Всем ку подскажите пожалуйста, как мне из отправленного сообщение бота достать текст ?

```
async def add(ctx, *, message, msg_id: int = None, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    if not msg_id:
        channel = bot.get_channel() # the message's channel
        msg_id =  # the message's id
    elif not channel:
        channel = ctx.channel
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
    hch = (msg,message)
    await ctx.send(hch)
```

Для примера я хотел сделать так, условно прошлое сообщение бота "Я хочу пиццу" + моё сообщение из команды "Всем ку!" = сообщение от бота "Я хочу пиццу Всем ку"

На практики выходит так
(<Message id=1069413274027831396 channel= type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=1061292038726877344 name='Кладовщик' discriminator='3401' bot=True nick=None guild=> flags=>, 'Всем ку')

Как исправить, чтобы бот писал текст прошлого сообщение, а не его значения ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, стоит сказать, что у Вас полная неразбериха в коде.

1. Вы ставите знак ***`*`*** в самом начале, что делает код просто не понятным. Ставить ***`*`*** необходимо тогда, когда Вы хотите записывать весь введенный текст пользователем в переменную после него, в Вашем случае в ***`*, message`***. Изменяем Вашу строку:

```
async def add(ctx, msg_id: int = None, channel: discord.TextChannel = None, *, message):
```

2. Так же у Ваших переменных ***`msg_id`*** и ***`channel`*** первоначальное значение ***`None`***, что будет некорректно работать. Меняем:

```
async def add(ctx, msg_id: int, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, message):
```

Во-вторых множество ненужных проверок. Всё что нам нужно, это получить текст сообщения которое мы получим по указанному ID:

```
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
```

Далее достаточно отправить сообщение:

```
    await ctx.send(f"{msg.content} \n{message}")
```

1. ***`{msg.content}`*** - получаем текст сообщения которое мы получили по ID:
2. ***`\n`*** - следующей строкой..
3. ***`{message}`*** - отправляем текст который мы указали и записали в переменную ***`message`***.

Полный код:

```
async def add(ctx, msg_id: int, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, message):
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
    await ctx.send(f"{msg.content} \n{message}")
```

Что мы получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я Вам помог, отметьте этот ответ галочкой и полезным.